# computational complexity of T(n)=T(n-1)+n

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

I have to calculate the computational complexity and computational complexity class of T(n) = T(n-1) + n.
My problem is that I don't know any method to do so and the only one I'm familiar with is universal recursion which doesn't apply to this task.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is a mathematics question.

Answer (score 2):

```
T(0) = a
T(n) = T(n-1) + n

n    T(n)
---------
0    a
1    T(1-1) + n = a + 1
2    T(2-1) + n = a + 1 + 2
3    T(3-1) + n = a + 1 + 2 + 3
...
k    T(k-1) + n = a + 1 + 2 + ... + k
                = a + k(k+1)/2
```

Guess T(n) = O(n^2) based on the above. We can prove it by induction.

Base case: T(1) = T(0) + 1 = a + 1 <= c*1^2 provided that c >= a + 1.

Induction hypothesis: assume T(n) <= c*n^2 for all n up to and including k.

Induction step: show that T(k+1) <= c*(k+1)^2. We have

```
T(k+1) = T(k) + k + 1 <= c*k^2 + k + 1
<= c*k^2 + 2k + 1          // provided k >= 0
<= c*(k^2 + 2k + 1)        // provided c >= 1
= c*(k+1)^2
```

We know k >= 0 and we can choose c to be the greater of a+1 and 1, which must reasonably be a+1 since T(0) is nonnegative.

Comment: Is this methodology a general one? Every time I look for some videos about computing the time complexity of an algorithm the methodology is different, sometimes it is just intuitive... I am looking for a solution that can be generalized...

Comment: @Bionix1441 "Proof by induction" is "general" in the sense that it can be applied to lots of different things you'd like to prove. The method for generating the "guess" we went on to prove is "general" in the sense that you can write out a few terms of any recursive function and look for a pattern. However, there is no truly general scheme for proving the asymptotic bounds of general recursive functions.